# Function won't loop

Tags: python, loops, return, function

I've made a piece of code which works fine with print but fails when I made a function of it and tried to return it. Here's the original code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wikipedia

source_code = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM')
plain_text = source_code.text
plain_text = plain_text[:plain_text.find('id="toc"')]
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

for div in soup.findAll('a'):
    if div.parent.name == 'p':
        href = div.get('href')
        href = href.replace(',', '')
        href = href.replace('-', ' ')
        href = href.replace('(', '')
        href = href.replace(')', '')
        href = href.replace('_', ' ')

        print (href[6:])
        href = href.replace(' ', '_')
        href = href.replace(' ^ ', '')
        try:
            print(wikipedia.summary(href[6:]))
        except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
            print (e.options)
```

which formats the text and gives me a title and the summary of a wikipedia page and all the summaries of the links in the original summary, which is exactly what I want. Unfortunately, this needs to be part of a bigger program and therefore i made a function (maybe I should do it in another way?)
it looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wikipedia

source_code = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM')
plain_text = source_code.text
plain_text = plain_text[:plain_text.find('id="toc"')]
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

def ELS():
    for div in soup.findAll('a'):
        if div.parent.name == 'p':
            href = div.get('href')
            href = href.replace(',', '')
            href = href.replace('-', ' ')
            href = href.replace('(', '')
            href = href.replace(')', '')
            href = href.replace('_', ' ')

            return href[6:]
            href = href.replace(' ', '_')
            href = href.replace(' ^ ', '')
            try:
                return wikipedia.summary(href[6:])
            except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                return e.options

print (ELS())
```

but for some reason, it doesn't loop and just prints the first title and then breaks, maybe it's an easy problem and just something i've missed

Comment: When you use `return`, the function returns immediately, so the loop ends.

Comment: Don't return inside the loop, concatenate the value onto a result string. Return that string after the loop is done.

Comment: Okey, thought it might be something like that, thank you :)

Comment: @SamuelHåkansson concatenation is slow. You should collect all substrings inside a list and build your final string with the `join` method or transform your function into a generator by replacing `return` with 'yield'. The later is arguably preferable due to versatility.

Answer (score 1):

`return` immediately exits the function.

Collect the information in a list and return that:

```
def ELS():
    results = []
    for div in soup.findAll('a'):
        if div.parent.name == 'p':
            href = div.get('href')
            href = href.replace(',', '')
            href = href.replace('-', ' ')
            href = href.replace('(', '')
            href = href.replace(')', '')
            href = href.replace('_', ' ')

            href = href.replace(' ', '_')
            href = href.replace(' ^ ', '')
            try:
                results.append((href[6:], wikipedia.summary(href[6:])))
            except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                results.append((href[6:], e.options))
    return results
```

You can then loop over the results; each entry is a tuple with the processed `href` value and the `wikipedia.summary()` output or the exception `e.options` attribute. This then lets you further reuse this information in other code.

Comment: I've tried with:
    summaryList = []

(code )
 
            try:
                summaryList.append(wikipedia.summary(href[6:]))
            except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                summaryList.append(e.options)
    return summaryList

Comment: Not sure whether it's intentional, but behaviour is slightly different to OP's code because you're appending `href[6:]` after the last two replacements.

Comment: I've tried with add or change:
summaryList=[]
        try:
            summaryList.append(wikipedia.summary(href[6:]))
        except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
            summaryList.append(e.options)
return summaryList

errors:
File..worder.py", line 102, in <module>
WTD()
File..worder.py", line 69, in WTD
textFile.write(repr(ELS()) + '\n')
File..\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03c4' in position 11342: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @zehnpaard right, that was not intentional; storing that in a new variable would be an option.

Comment: @SamuelHåkansson you'll need to use an explicit encoding when opening your file; the default encoding of CP1252 ( the Windows codepage for western characters) cannot handle everything Wikiepedia can produce in titles.

Answer (score 1):

You just replace print with return, and your function behaviour now has a problem, because the function ends its execution when the command return is called.

Try something like this:

```
def ELS():
    output = []
    for div in soup.findAll('a'):
        if div.parent.name == 'p':
            href = div.get('href')
            href = href.replace(',', '')
            href = href.replace('-', ' ')
            href = href.replace('(', '')
            href = href.replace(')', '')
            href = href.replace('_', ' ')

            output.append(href[6:])
            href = href.replace(' ', '_')
            href = href.replace(' ^ ', '')
            try:
                output.append(wikipedia.summary(href[6:]))
            except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                output.append(e.options)

    return "\n".join(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning out of your function, therefore breaking the loop. You need to add your search results to a list or a dict and return it after your loop.